# Saving addresses/pointers of QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I'm dynamically generating QWidgets (so far only labels) so that I can change the UI on the fly. I know I can use XML files from QTCreator, but I've got my reasons not to.

Anyway, everytime I create a widget, I pass the type (label) and address to a vector. That works fine. But when I try to cast the address back to a QLabel (for example) and do '&castedQLabel' it gives me a different result.

Here is a pseudo code of what is happening:

```
 vector_of_Widgets.push_back({tmpString, "label", &origLabel}); 
 qDebug() << &origLabel;

//Later in code
QLabel *tmpLabel = (QLabel *)vector_of_QWidgets[number].data; //.data is the third argument ^^
qDebug() << vector_of_QWidgets[number].data;
qDebug() << &tmpLabel;
```

Output:

```
>>0x7ffc151a5518 

>>0x7ffc151a5518 
>>0x7ffc151a4ab0
```

Oh yeah, also, .data is (void *).

Comment: `&tmpLabel` is the address of `tmpLabel` itself, not the address it points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmpLabel points to your QLabel, no need to dereference it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, It should then be ` qDebug() << &(*tmpLabel); ` ?

Comment: &(*pointer) is the same as pointer, so you can just write:

    qDebug() << tmpLabel;

Comment: I've tried that already, but It just gives me a segmentation error. I just can't find out why. Though, the problem may not be where I think it is. Any ideas on how to debug it?

Comment: Make sure you QLabel has not been destroyed in-between since I suppose it is allocated on the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure how It could be destroyed if it is still displayed. It should be allocated on the heap: `QLabel *origLabel = new QLabel(str_html, this);`

Comment: Therefore you should only store origLabel, not &origLabel  which is the address of your pointer to the QLabel (and this pointer is allocated on the stack).

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid now. I understand what I was doing wrong.